# OnPrem IIS upload and serve images

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, iis-7.5

I’m having to build some functionality on premise which allows users to upload files via an api.

1. What’s the best way of storing these files. At the moment we use sql and I want to move away from that
2. what’s the best way of generating static urls to serve these back to the client? I basically want a <img src=‘https://localhost/app/image1.jpeg’ ...

Answer (score 0):

If the image name is not an issue I'd invoke a NewGuid.Guid() after the file is uploaded rename and save in a lookup table in SQL.

You are guaranteed unique file names. You are able to create a lookup table and can store original file name, user specific information, etc. in SQL.

If storage & iteration over a large set of files is a concern create a folder mapping using date/time so you have fewer images in a folder. like /app/2020/11/02/

Comment: Thanks. I’m thinking of building a page handler ashx to return the request

Comment: Yes that is how my last CMS functioned. All media items (photo, video, audio, document) were returned as ASHX requests. Easy to manage in the system. We returned attributes like mim-type, extension, and H/W to make the content work in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload and store the image the best way is you and store the uploaded file name in the database and retrieve it with the static use which you want.

if you want to use the ashx you have to add the handle in iis:

```
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
</modules>
<handlers>
    <add name="ImageUploadHandler" verb="*" path="ImageUploadHandler.ashx" type="JetAdz.WebApi.ImageUploadHandler, JetAdz.WebApi, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
</handlers>
```

</system.webServer>